# TListView - How to control the rect item size in Viewstyle = vsIcon?

Tags: delphi, tlistview

I need to draw custom 120 x 120 thmbnails on a TListView in `Viewstyle = vsIcon`.  without using `LargeImages` (I will paint on "OnCustomDrawItem").

The only way I could make this work is to specify a "dummy" TImageList for `LargeImages` with width/heigh = 120.

otherwise the item rect is undefined (also with OwnerDraw=True)

How to do this?